# Dynamic content added with Angular4 click not working when create new div

Tags: html, angular, typescript

When i create a new div on the same document body, lets say a stack of divs, i loose the references to the .ts funtions on the previous div, i've tryed to emulate this with a button, so i have the div with:

```
<div id="foo">
<button type="button" id="btn1" (click)="clickButton()">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

This works.. Now i click on one function  on that div that creates a new div with new content, the new created button (click)="clickButton()" works on that last div, but not works anymore on the previous one (the opened one in first place)
(the button only works on the last opened div, but not on the previous divs.. )

my .ts has:

```
clickButton = function() {
alert("button clicked");
};
```

ps: im working with angular4 and typescript:

Comment: Try removing the id or assign new id dynamincally using [attr.id] = "'foo'+index"

Comment: tryed that, but doesn't work.. check my new post, with my code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solutioned it, just had to add a Jquery function onInit, that checks if the button, on that particular div, is clicked and then calls the funtion.

Html:

```
<button data-id="{{eval('relatedInstance.instance.' + property.key + '.' + property.concept.idKey)}}" data-name="{{property.concept.name}}" >Click Me2</button>
```

typeScript:

```
$("div").on("click","button","", test);
   function test(){
      //alert($(this).data("id") + 'Clicked!' + this.id);
   alert(this.name+ ' - ' +this.id);
   };
```

hope this helps somebody with the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try after removing id from button or assign new id on the element using [attr.id] = "'foo'+index"